# Cannot validate with table record while logging in using Python

Tags: python, passlib

I have my own signin/login functionality in my APP. At the time registering I am encrypting the password using `passlib hash` method and storing the encrypted value inside table. But my problem is while I am trying to logged in it could not match the value using Python.

Here is my code:

```
def signsave(request):
    name = request.POST.get('uname')
    password = request.POST.get('pass')
    con_pass = request.POST.get('conpass')
    new_pass = sha256_crypt.encrypt( password )
    hash = new_pass
    if password == con_pass:
       passw = User(
             uname=name,
             password=new_pass,
             raw_password=password,
       )
    passw.save()
```

Here I am saving all credentials in table.

```
def loginsave(request):
    password = request.POST.get('pass')
    uname = request.POST.get('uname')
    new_pass = sha256_crypt.encrypt( password )
    per = User.objects.all().filter(
            Q(password__icontains=new_pass) &
            Q(uname__icontains=uname)).count()
```

Here again I am trying to encrypt the registered password and matched with table but its not working and count is coming 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to hash the password again when trying to log in. You need to get the existing hash out of the database and use `.verify()` on it. There's an example on the homepage of passlib about how to use it: https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/